# Prove the inequality for $x,y,z\in{\mathbb R^+}$

Tags: inequality

Please prove the inequality:

$$x^{\frac{x}{x+y+z}}\cdot y^{\frac{y}{x+y+z}}\cdot z^{\frac{z}{x+y+z}}\le\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}$$

I changed the domain to R^+ as it seems there is no reason to require that $x,y,z$ be integer.
I tries to prove it by convexity (Jensen's Theorem) that usually work for such problems with powers of $x,y,z$ but I could not work it out.

Comment: Don't you mean $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: $x,y,z \in \mathbb R^+$ I presume?

Comment: @am301: positive integers are not represented by $\mathbb{Z}$, appearing in the title. Many users here tend to downvote so-called PSQs (Problem Statement Questions) like yours, and answers, too (some god will forgive them, but the poor human Jack won't). So it is in your (and community's) best interest to improve your actual question by adding some context (your attempts, why this question is relevant to you, something along these lines). Cheers.

Comment: Set of positive integers is $\mathbb Z^+$. It was stated to me this way, but I understand it could also don't see why it wouldn't apply to all of $\mathbb  R^+$. I have been trying to prove the inequality with no success yet. Will appreciate all help.

Comment: I tried to solve this problem with convexity (Jensen's theorem) but for got it messed up.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Follows directly from weighted AM-GM, with weights $\frac{x}{x+y+z},$ and so on.